# Macro to run a specific block of code inside another macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have four or five macro's each copying and pasting different subsets of data (all defined as ranges) from one tab to another tab. Occasionally someone may need to change some of the pasted data or rather portions of this.

Each of these macro's contains defined points I can goto.  BUT  if I needed to get to these points from another macro without running the bit before the goto point in the target macro - how can I do this.

I can call or application.run the second macro, but I need only run a part of it, not the whole thing.

I am a bit stuck.

Here is the part of the code which defines the goto point in one of the target macro's.

```
Grade:
        Grades = Application.InputBox("Which Grade chemistry do you wish to load & Check against" & vbLf & vbLf & "1. S355 J2H" & vbLf & vbLf & "2. S355NH" & vbLf & vbLf & "3. S355NLH" & vbLf & vbLf, "Select which option to load")
        Select Case Grades
                Case 1
                        Ans = MsgBox("You have selected S355J2H is this correct?", vbYesNo) ' allows a loop if you have made a mistake and will take you back to the selection option
                        If Ans = vbNo Then GoTo Grade Else:
                                rng8.Copy: rng7.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                                                :=False, Transpose:=False
                                ws.Activate
                                Columns("BC:BD").Select
                                With Selection.Font
                                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
                                .TintAndShade = 0
                                End With
                Case 2
                        Ans = MsgBox("You have selected S355NH is this correct?", vbYesNo) ' allows a loop if you have made a mistake and will take you back to the selection option
                        If Ans = vbNo Then GoTo Grade Else:
                                rng8a.Copy: rng7.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                                                :=False, Transpose:=False
                                ws.Activate
                                Columns("BC:BD").Select
                                With Selection.Font
                                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
                                .TintAndShade = 0
                                End With
                Case 3
                        Ans = MsgBox("You have selected S355NLH is this correct?", vbYesNo) ' allows a loop if you have made a mistake and will take you back to the selection option
                        If Ans = vbNo Then GoTo Grade Else:
                                rng8b.Copy: rng7.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                                                :=False, Transpose:=False
                                ws.Activate
                                Columns("BC:BD").Select
                                With Selection.Font
                                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
                                .TintAndShade = 0
                                End With
                Case Else ' this is where no input or an alternative input is done, it will exit the subroutine
                    dummy = MsgBox("wrong input please try again", vbCritical)
                    Exit Sub

        End Select
```

There is a similar code before this step, which I do NOT want to run and I would ideally like to not repeat this code and others from the target macro's in a separate macro, and call this new macro. When I need to update the information it means updating in multiple places instead one just the one or two maximum.

Comment: Perhaps that section should be its own `Sub`. But this sounds suspicious: "Each of these macro's contains defined points I can goto". `GoTo` should be avoided, it generally creates spaghetti code. Sounds like you need some refactoring.

Comment: Instead of `Goto's`, you can have this in a **Loop**. Also, your `Case Else` suggests try again but exits the sub.. seems a bit misleading

Comment: it exits the sub to enable them to restart the macro and avoid a continuous loop.  At the moment (I will update this later).  I am trying to completely avoid having extra sub's.  hence my question.

Comment: BigBen - what should I use instead of Goto?  I am a newby to VBA and trying to teach myself through books, trial and error and this forum!

Answer (score 0):

As BigBen suggested, you need to refactor your code. Copy the below code in a `Module`

```
Option Explicit

Public rRng8 As Range, rRng8a As Range, rRng8b As Range


Sub CopyRange(rCopyToRng As Range)

    Dim iGrade As Long, iAns As Long, iTryAgain As Long

    ' Set Default Values
    iAns = vbNo
    iTryAgain = vbYes

    ' Loop to copy the correct range
    Do While iAns <> vbYes And iTryAgain <> vbNo

        ' Get grade
        iGrade = Application.InputBox("Which Grade chemistry do you wish to load & Check against" & vbLf & vbLf & "1. S355 J2H" & vbLf & vbLf & "2. S355NH" & vbLf & vbLf & "3. S355NLH" & vbLf & vbLf, "Select which option to load", , , , , , 1)

        ' Case to select the correct range to copy
        Select Case iGrade
            Case 1
                iAns = MsgBox("You have selected S355J2H is this correct?", vbYesNo)
                If iAns = vbYes Then CopyRangeHelper rCopyToRng, rRng8
            Case 2
                iAns = MsgBox("You have selected S355NH is this correct?", vbYesNo)
                If iAns = vbYes Then CopyRangeHelper rCopyToRng, rRng8a
            Case 3
                iAns = MsgBox("You have selected S355NLH is this correct?", vbYesNo)
                If iAns = vbYes Then CopyRangeHelper rCopyToRng, rRng8b
            Case Else

                ' If the user entere incorrect number, ask if the want to try again
                iTryAgain = MsgBox("Wrong input. Do you want to try again?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo)

        End Select

    Loop

End Sub


Sub CopyRangeHelper(rCopyToRange As Range, rRngToCopy As Range)

    ' Copy range
    rRngToCopy.Copy: rCopyToRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                        :=False, Transpose:=False

    ' Set range format
    With rCopyToRange
        .Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .Interior.TintAndShade = 0
    End With

End Sub
```

> **NOTE:** You don't need to use `Select` or `Activate`. You just reference what you need to work with

**How to use this:**
Below is a sample UDF that calls `CopuRange` UDF to perform the action

```
Sub TestThis()

    Dim oWS As Worksheet: Set oWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")       ' Change sheet reference

    Set rRng8 = oWS.Range("A1:A16")                                         ' Set ranges as required
    Set rRng8a = oWS.Range("B1:B16")
    Set rRng8b = oWS.Range("C1:C16")

    CopyRange ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A1:A16")             ' Change sheet reference and range

End Sub
```